# merging two images with triangle crop

Tags: image, image-manipulation, gimp, inkscape

In Eagle, I've created a circuit that consists of schematic and PCB layout. From Schematic and PCB Layout I've created screenshots in .jpg format. Now, how do I merge these two screenshots with triangle crop just like in example below (left image, sch&pcb merged):[image: following example]. I am using KUbuntu 15.04 with gimp, pinta and inkscape image manipulation applications. Oh, I forgot, the screenshots are neither same ratio neither same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the images are in the same ratio, you can use GIMP:

- open both images in gimp
- select smallest image and copy it to the clipboard
- paste clipboard content as a layer into the largest image
- transform/scale layer (shift + t), find a best mapping with the background image (you can hide a layer with click on an "eye" in layers window, use lock scaling if appropriate for your image ratio)
- in an overlapped layer select a triangle, and press delete button